# Is there a limitation on the numbers of layers that can be displayed in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, limitations

I have been looking for an answer to this question for the last several weeks, so hope that someone here has encountered the same issue and has a viable solution to my problem.  I am currently using the following configuration:

•   Windows 7 Pro

•   QGIS 2.2 (also tested 2.4 with same issue on a separate system)

The issue I am seeing is that that once I reach 254 or 256 layers added to a project, as soon as I add any additional layers, all layers disappear from my map and I am unable to see any of my data.  I work with large amounts of data.  Is this a limitation in QGIS or is it a setting somewhere?  I have also tested MapInfo, which I am thinking of buying if QGIS is unable to handle the load; MapInfo does not have this limitation.

Any ideas?  I can provide more information if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Fyi sounds like a "max no. open files limit":  http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4013

Comment: Hi mdsumner, Thanks for the quick reply but I did see this post and it did not provide a clear solution to this issue.  I also seen that the post was geared more towards MAC OS not Windows.  Like I stated before, I tested loading all my data into MapInfo and I don't see the problem, so I am thinking that the issues is with the QGIS software application; if the OS would be at fault I would have seen it with any GIS software I would have thought.

Comment: Consider Manifold over Mapinfo btw.

Comment: Manifold sounds like a great tool but no free trial so I doubt my group will spend money to test a tool that they don't know if it will meet all the requirements and/or like :-).  Thanks

Comment: Having +255 layers open in MapInfo feels suboptimal but I believe that you know your task and can't organize it to smaller projects.

Comment: I agree, for most of our drive test data, <254 is enough but this is dictated by the size of our drive test area.  I have been able to breakout the data displayed into clusters but if I want to display a complete map of what has been driven I am unable to do it with this limitation.  This said, I have been testing other tools, like MapInfo, and they do not have this limitation.  Anyone have any idea how to get around this issue?

Comment: For display purpose push all your routes into one or a few database tables and classify them for viewing by route-ID. It looks like one layer can have 999 classes but I am not sure. 254 layers * 999 classes makes quite a lot. Too simple?

Comment: Does one of those layers have a bad geometry, I have seen that make the map stop rendering correctly.  Not sure why but something to consider.

Comment: I have lunched abut 450 vector layers (shp files with a lot of class, WIN XP) without problems. Probably some files have an error which stops opening process. The way is how to find it ? If it's possible try other GIS software to import your data ex. Geomedia, Arcgis ?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be [more of an operating system limit](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/4013), not something defined in QGIS. It's been [further documented here](https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Known_Issues), only with a focus on Linux. As mentioned in the above link, keep in mind that when using shapefiles in particular, you're actually opening three files. Beyond the open file limit, there are practical constraints on RAM, video card memory, and other machine capacities.