# Has QGis 3.4 some limitation for filenumber to load shp files?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, limitations

I want to load over 600 shp files at once in qgis 3.4. Is there a limitation on the number of shapefiles that can be added?

Comment: Do you get an error when you try? See: [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113287/is-there-a-limitation-on-the-numbers-of-layers-that-can-be-displayed-in-qgis).

Comment: To summarize the other answer: there's no *specific* limit on the number of shapefiles you can load in QGIS. There will be a limit, but it depends entirely on your exact situation (your system, hardware, other programs running, size of shapefiles, etc. etc.) The only way to find out your limit it to try it on your system.

Comment: Just based on my own experience, I would say that 600 sounds like a lot. If I tried that on my computer, I would expect it to freeze.